# Getting Run-Time Exception in implementation of Priority Queue in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

I have been solving problems in an online competitive coding forum and came across this problem : http://www.spoj.com/problems/PQUEUE/.  I have implemented the same in Java and it is working fine for all the test cases I can think of. However, it is getting a NZEC when I tried to submit my code. Given below is portion of my code. The input range is well handled. So don't worry about that. Here, `in` is an object of `Scanner` class.

```
int t = in.nextInt(), i, k, count;

    while (t-- > 0) {
        ArrayDeque<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            k = in.nextInt();
            q.offer(k);
            ar.add(k);
        }

        Collections.sort(ar, Collections.reverseOrder());
        count = 0;
        int num = 0, max = ar.get(0), pos = m;

        while (true) {
            num = q.peek();
            if (max > num) {
                if (pos == 0)
                    pos = n - 1;
                else
                    pos--;
                q.removeFirst();
                q.offer(num);

            } else {
                if (pos == 0)
                    break;
                else
                    pos--;
                count++;
                q.removeFirst();
                ar.remove(0);
                max = ar.get(0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count + 1);
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have been going at this code for days now, yet without any clue as to where I am getting the error. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What exception are you getting ?

Comment: Non-Zero exit code(NZEC). I don't know the details, but it's a run-time exception for particular test case/s.